# Young tableau in figure caption

Tags: captions, packages, youngtab

Is there a way to insert a Young diagram or tableau inside a figure caption,  using either the `youngtab` or `ytableau` packages, or otherwise?

The simple synthax of just adding - say - `$\yng(3)$` does not compile (at least on Overleaf).

An example that produces the basic figure and caption and works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{youngtab}
\usepackage{ytableau}

\begin{document}

This shows the inline Young diagram: $\yng(3)$

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.7]{universe}
\caption{The Universe;}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Adding $\yng(3)$ to the caption no longer works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{youngtab}
\usepackage{ytableau}

\begin{document}

This shows the inline Young diagram: $\yng(3)$.

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.7]{universe}
\caption{The Universe; $\yng(3)$}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably fragile, have you tried `$\protect\yng(3)$`, else please provide a full minimal example others can copy and test as is. Here we have to guess 95% of an example, and most people does not bother.

Comment: @daleif Thanks.  Just added the basic code plus the extra bit that makes it crash in two separate examples.

Comment: @daleif using $\protect$ seems to do the trick thanks!

Comment: My welcome on TeX.SE.....from also PSE community. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks.  I did not realize you were such an aficionado.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Ahahahah :-) I like very very .....much LaTeX :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\caption` is a moving target and potentially needs to write its argument to a file (for the list of whatever). Some commands are fragile and thus cannot readily be used in a moving target. Often this can be mitigated by using protection (pun intended):

```
$\protect\yng(3)$
```